# Difference between w3total cache disk enhanced and disk basic

Tags: plugin-w3-total-cache

Regarding the w3total cache working mechanism, I searched the internet but couldnt find any proper information regarding these two. What is the difference between the disk enhanced and disk basic in w3Total cache.And why is disk enhanced preferred over disk basic? What the advantages and disadvantages of using the options disk enhanced and disk cache repectively?

Comment: [This article](http://blog.loadimpact.com/tag/w3-total-cache/) explains the difference.

Comment: Thnks this article helped me to know more stats and differnce about the cache plugins and mechanisms

Answer (score 7):

You should use "Enhanced" if it's available. It serves cached pages using the server's URL rewriting capabilities, skipping PHP and WordPress entirely. It's faster and more efficient.

Comment: Now I can consider this option of W3 an alternative to wp super cache expert mode